# findViewByID in Android Studio not working with EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid

I can't seem to get `findViewById()` working with the EditText. It works fine with the button, but I think I am doing something wrong and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. How does `findViewById()` work with EditText ?

Here is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button sbutton;
    EditText book, chapter, verse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton);

        book = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.book1);
        chapter = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.chapter1);
        verse = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.verse1);
    }
}
```

And here is my XML:

```
<TextView android:text="Please enter your favorite scripture" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/book1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chapter1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/verse1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/sbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="77dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Book"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/book"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chapter"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/book"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Verse"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chapter"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I know this might not be the nicest code because I'm brand new to Android Studio. I would appreciate a little help understanding how this method works and what I might be doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it as "findViewByID()" but its findViewById()

```
sbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton);
book = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.book1);
chapter = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.chapter1);
verse = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.verse1);
```

**Correct method name is**

```
findViewById()

sbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton);

book = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.book1);
chapter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chapter1);
verse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.verse1);
```